# CopyOnWriteArrayList is zero instead of actual size?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Probably something simple, but I can't figure it out on my own. I have some sample of Spring Boot WebSockets implementation and wanted to display total active sessions. So I created `@Scheduled` `activeSessions` task, which should display actual count, but it's always 0. When `afterConnectionEstablished` is called I get expected sessions size. Whats the catch?

```
@Configuration
public class Monitoring extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    private List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
            throws Exception {

        String clientMessage = message.getPayload();
        System.out.println(clientMessage);
        sessions.forEach(s -> {
            try {
                s.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Hello! You session id is: " + s.getId()));
                activeSessions();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        //the messages will be broadcasted to all users.
        System.out.println("Adding new session.");
        sessions.add(session);
        System.out.println("Current session count: " + sessions.size());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        sessions.remove(session);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
    public void activeSessions() {
        System.out.println("Total sessions: " + sessions.size());
    }
}
```

Configuration part:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(@NotNull WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new Monitoring(), "/socket");
    }
}
```

Due [conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343692/websocketconfigurer-and-scheduled-are-not-work-well-in-an-application) described, custom scheduler:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingConfig {

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343692/websocketconfigurer-and-scheduled-are-not-work-well-in-an-application

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(10);
        taskScheduler.initialize();
        return taskScheduler;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your full class... Including class header etc. and how you configure this handler. My guess is you either have 2 instances (you could include the `hashcode` in the messages or you have something in there that prevents a proxy being properly created leading to reading values from the proxy instead of the embedded instance.

Comment: Edited my post. Yes indeed, I tried it with ArrayList - exactly same. So maybe really two instances are created. So already good direction to look for solution.

Comment: I'm certain it are 2 instances. Remove `@Configuration` and remove the `new Monitor` from your `WebSocketConfig`. Replace it with an `@Bean` method that creates the `Monitoring` that way you have a single instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have 2 separate instances of the `Monitoring` class. One created by yourself, doing the request handling (which isn't a Spring managed bean!) and another one detected by Spring due to the `@Configuration` (shouldn't that be an `@Component`?).

Remove the `@Configuration` and replace it with an `@Bean` method, such that your `WebSocketConfig` looks like the following

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(@NotNull WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(monitoring(), "/socket");
    }

    @Bean
    public Monitoring monitoring() {
        return new Monitoring();
    }
}
```

You now have a single instance of the bean, managed by Spring.

Comment: Thanks for idea. At the moment it looks like this: If I remove `@EnableWebSocket`, than single `Monitoring` is created, but I get 404 if I try to open socket. If I add `@EnableWebSocket` again two instances are created (added logging to Monitoring constructor). More ideas how to rule it out?

Comment: Have you removed `@Configuration` from the `Monitoring` class as I stated. Hmm I was under the impression web sockets would automatically be enabled when detected on the classpath... Apparently I was wrong. Also it *might* appear as if 2 instances are being created as 1 is a proxy. So don't be fooled by the logs.

Comment: I think I will figure it out how to get it working, thanks!